# jQuery On function doesn't work in IE when we ctrl + click an element with an 'href' containing a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

How can we use [jQuery's On function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to catch and handle click events for anchor tags that contain valid URL's, in Internet Explorer?

In Internet Explorer (all versions), when we give an anchor tag an `href` attribute containing a valid URL (e.g, `<a href="http://google.com">valid URL in anchor tag</a>`) and click the link, jQuery's On function doesn't catch and handle the elements `click`event.

I've tested jQuery versions: 1.8.3; 1.10.2; 1.11.1; 2.1.1

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/id_0t/nfmn9g4h/1/)

HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com">hold control and click me (doesn't pop alert)</a>
<a href="#">hold control and click me (no href, this works)</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {

    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('If you see this alert, problem solved!')
    }

});
```

Comment: This one => [http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/ydru70tb/](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/ydru70tb/)

Comment: Thank you @LShetty for your response however as indicated in the fiddle provided in my original post, `e.which ==` doesn't solve this issue. Before asking this question I attempted multiple variations (as outlined in my question and Fiddle) without luck, only to stumble across the fact that the URL being added to the anchor tag is culprit, with no obvious solution. But, again... thanks for looking at this at all.